# Using register contents as labels

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, label

Picture this:

Say ECX == 3.

And I want the number '65' i.e ASCII 'A' as a label for my code:

```
;NB This is an example/code snippet

mov ecx, 65
    jmp .%+[ecx]  
    ...

    .A: 
       [do stuff here]
```

When I compile code using the above idea, it gives me the following:

```
error: comma, colon or end of line expected
```

What I'm asking is what syntax errors am I making- I'm pretty sure I am following the label definition rules outlined in the Chapter 3.1 in the NASM Manual:

"...The only characters which may be used as the first character of an identifier are letters, . (with special meaning: see section 3.9), _ and ?... "

Also, I ask if there are more efficient solutions to my problem at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't "compute" labels in assembly. But you can compute addresses.

Here `ecx` will be used as an index into a table containing addresses corresponding to multiple labels:

```
    mov ecx, 65
    jmp [table - 'A'*4 + ecx*4]
    ...

table:
    dd .A ; address of .A:
    dd .B ; address of .B:
    dd .C ; address of .C:
    ...

.A:
   [do stuff here]
.B:
   [do stuff here]
.C:
   [do stuff here]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Alexey. I guess moving 65 into EAX also proved another point about operator precedence within names (i.e. [table - 'A'*4 + ecx*4]), whether multiplication occurs before addition or not.

Comment: I don't think NASM has unusual precedence for +-\*/.